# How do we filter results from two tables using prefetch_related function in Django

Tags: python, django

This is my code:

```
question_list = Question.objects.filter(category=category, is_approved=1) \
                                .prefetch_related('answer_set')[:10]
```

I am filtering question by `is_approved` and want this filter on answer also.

I would also want a limit on answer i.e '2'. Any help? I know its a simple question but i am new to django.

I have same `is_approved` field in answer also.

I have question table and answer table. Answer table has a foreign key of question_id. Every question have as many as answers. And i want to fetch all questions with there answers but limit on answers i.e 2 in a single query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `answer__is_appoved=1` lookup.  And don't forget to add `distinct()` call to the queryset:

```
question_list = Question.objects.distinct() \
                        .filter(category=category, is_approved=1,
                                answer__is_approved=1) \
                        .prefetch_related('answer_set')[:10]
```

If you want to get list of approved questions with two approved answers then use `Count` annotation:

```
from django.db.models import Count

question_list = Question.objects.distinct() \
                        .filter(category=category, is_approved=1,
                                answer__is_approved=1) \
                        .annotate(answer_cnt=Count('answer')) \
                        .filter(answer_cnt=2) \
                        .prefetch_related('answer_set')[:10]
```

But note that `prefetch_related()` fetches all answer regardless of `is_approved` property.  So you have to filter then manually:

```
for question in question_list:
    approved_answers = [answer for question.answer_set.all()
                               if answer.is_approved == 1]
```

Comment: With this i am unable to get any related question. And i also want a limit on answer.

Comment: What do you mean? `for q in question_list: print q.answer_set.all()` should work as usual.

Comment: And explain "limit on answer", please.

Comment: I mean if all answers for a particular question have  is_approved  as 0. Then the above question_list would not show the result for question table also which have  is_approved  as 1. And i need all the questions result set with only 2 answers result set.

Comment: You want to get questions which have two approved answers?  Then see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i need every question with maximum 2 of its answer. Therefore i think filter would not a good idea to use.

Comment: You can use `filter(answer_cnt__lte=2)` o get questions with zero, one or two approved questions.